# script to obtain a single equation

Tags: python, parsing, text, equation, text-parsing

#Input in textfile :

```
a=2+8,b=3+9,c=4+8,d=5+9,e=a+b,f=c+d,g=0+6,h=1+7,i=e*g,j=f+h,output=i+j
```

#Desired Output:
output=(((2+8)+(3+9))*(0+6))+(((4+8)+(5+9))*(1+7))

Comment: Assigning to literal integers is an error, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: ok, then I will just rename the first column to be an alphabet. I need a single equation as output to do lower level computations further.

Comment: Having numbers represent sometimes themselves, sometimes something else doesn't really make sense...

Comment: You should probably describe more accurately your *real* use case.

Comment: I have modified the question.

Comment: Is the *input* in a file or do you acquire it some other way?

Comment: It is in a file, I can have it as a dataframe in csv or text.

Comment: What do you want to do with the output? Evaluate it (then how?) Keep it as text? Is the input only numerical (with no variables)? If it is the case, like in your examples, why not simply calculate it? Please clarify.

Comment: The input file is actually with no variables, but I can change the LHS in each line to be a unique variable because assigning to literal integers is an error. I need the final equation from where I can do hardware mapping. I am a hardware engineer, I get this results from a compiler, I need it in a equation format to proceed my work. Thank you!

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion

Comment: How does your code receive the input and in what format?

Comment: It is a text file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If the input file is called var.txt and is **exactly** as specified in your question, then this will work:

```
D = dict()
output = None
with open('var.txt') as v:
    for line in v:
        k, v = line.strip().split('=')
        if k == 'output':
            output = v
        else:
            D[k] = v
    for k, v in D.items():
        output = output.replace(k, f'({v})')
    print(output)
```

(14*16)+(15*17)*34

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, Thank you so much for the precise code.

Comment: Hi!

Input :

a=2*8
b=3*9
c=4*8
d=5*9
e=a+b
f=c+d
g=0*6
h=1*7
i=e+g
j=f+h
output=i+j 

This throws output = (e+g)+(f+h) but i want contents of every variable inside this equation.

Comment: You have now effectively changed your question. Please re-read the first sentence in my Answer

Comment: I am sorry, I have no knowledge in these environments. I thought i should make the question simpler. But this is my actual problem. I need all the information in one equation.